# Is splitting your 3 settlements allowed?

Tags: kingdom-builder

Let's say I've placed settlements in two separate forests. In both forests there are still (more than) 3 fields free. Now I draw another forest card and have to place my 3 settlements.

[image: initial situation (9 settlements already placed)]

**Am I allowed to split my 3 settlements and place 1 settlement in terrain A and 2 settlements in terrain B?** (next to my other settlements, of course)

Or do I have to build these 3 settlements in the *same* forest terrain, if possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hymie's answer is completely correct. Quoting from [the rulebook](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/70570/kingdom-builder-english-rules):

> the 3 settlements must be built successively *one after the other*.

And [BGG FAQ](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Kingdom_Builder_FAQ#):

> There is no rule that you must necessarily place your 3 settlements in a single contiguous group (though sometimes you *must*, and sometimes you may *choose* to).

Answer (score 10):

As long as you are next to your existing settlements and the terrain types match the card, there is no requirement that the three settlements that you play be in the same physical piece of terrain.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the rules if you have?? or something that make your answer more clear about why you said so?? thanks!

Comment: http://queen-games.de/games.aspx?ProductId=45  Page 4 of the rulebook outlines the building rules.

Comment: I'm guessing he "said so" because it's the correct answer! In any case, I'm more concerned with how the OP got settlements in two separate forests. It's possible... just curious :)

Comment: @gbianchi There is no rule that specifically states this is allowed, because it is clearly implied by the lack of any rule that says that all 3 of your settlements must be built adjacent to each other, or within the same chunk of terrain.  Each settlement is placed individually, following the rules for individual placement.

Comment: @TheChaz: It's just an example to get the situation clear ;-) (However, this very case should be possible when we assume that there is another quadrant at the bottom resp. at the left, which is not pictured here).

Answer (score 1):

You must build 3 settlements consecutively (which means all 3 right now, in a row, one after the other) during the current turn. So long as they are placed next to existing settlements, they can be split up.

Comment: Could you provide citation to substantiate this? This appears to be contradicted by the BGG FAQ, but then again, the BGG FAQ isn't cited either.

Answer (score 0):

What you are NOT allowed to do is use an ability while placing the mandatory settlements. For example:

1. Place one mandatory settlement
2. Use paddock to gallop it somewhere else
3. Build your remaining mandatories.

Those three settlements have to be played sequentially.